# How to delete rows in sequences in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to delete the rows in sequences as it is shown in the table below.

I want

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|   32 | 74.5 |       
|   45 | 35   |
|   46 | 32   |
|   47 | 37   |
|   48 | 35   |
+------+------+

to be

+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|   32 | 74.5 |
|   45 | 35   |
+------+------+
```

or one of any numbers (45-48) in the sequence needs to be left in the final table.

Here's the code that I tried and I am getting something like this:

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|   32 | 74.5 |       
|   45 | 35   |
|   46 | 32   |
|   48 | 35   |
+------+------+
```

```
   for i in range(len(a)-1):
       if a[i+1][0] - a[i][0] == 1:
          a1 = np.delete(a, (i), axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the difference between rows and finding which ones are greater than 1 is one approach. You can use this to index your larger array. Here's one way to do it, assuming `a` is a numpy array:

```
ix = [True] + (np.diff(a[:, 0]) > 1).tolist()  # account for first element with [True]
a[ix]
```

---

The issue with your code is that each iteration in your loop uses the original `a` which will not be updated as you delete entries. However, you don't want this to happen either unless you account for the changing indices as you remove rows from the array. A simpler approach is to find all occurences first then delete them altogether like the code I provided.